# Wait children component init in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

```js
export class OrderDetailComponent implements OnInit {
 isOpenReviewPDF: boolean;
 @ViewChild(forwardRef(() => OrderReviewPdfComponent)) orderReviewPdfComponent: OrderReviewPdfComponent;
 
 ngOnInit() {
 }
 
 pulic exportPdf() {
  this.isOpenReviewPDF = true;
  if (this.orderReviewPdfComponent.isViewInit) {
            // How can I wait this code
   doSomething();
  }
 }
}


export class OrderReviewPdfComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {
 public isViewInit = false;
 
 ngOnInit() {
 }
 
 ngAfterViewChecked() {
  this.isViewInit = true;
 }
}
```

```html
 <div *ngIf="isOpenReviewPDF">
 <order-review-pdf [commissionIncentive]="commissionIncentive"
  [orderEntry]="orderEntry" [siteSurvey]='siteSurvey'></order-review-pdf>
</div>
```

I have exportPdf() function on parent component. How can I wait this condition ( if(this.orderReviewPdfComponent.isViewInit) ) is true to run doSomething() function? Currently doSomething() never call.

Comment: I would make an output in the child that triggers as soon as it is ready, then the parent can do something when that output triggers. :)

Comment: Is Output emit event fit to this case? Could you help to example it?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to make sure that the `OrderReviewPdfComponent`(child) template is initialized, you can use the `AfterViewInit` lifecycle hook inside the `OrderDetailComponent`

`ngAfterViewInit` is called on a Component when it's template and templates of it's children are initialized. So you should be calling the `exportPdf()` in the `ngAfterViewInit` method of the `OrderDetailComponent` and you should be just fine.

```
export class OrderDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // You can be sure that the template of OrderDetailComponent
    // and any of its child components was initialized in here.
    this.exportPdf();
  }

  pulic exportPdf() {
    doSomething();
  }

}
```

Now if you want to call `exportPdf` in your `OrderDetailComponent` every time there's a change in your `OrderReviewPdfComponent`, then you can create an `@Output` property in your `OrderReviewPdfComponent` which would be of type `EventEmitter`. You can then call the `emit` method on it everytime there's a change:

```
import { ..., Output, ... } from '@angular/core';

export class OrderReviewPdfComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {
  @Output() somethingChanged: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>(null);

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    // This will inform OrderDetailComponent that OrderReviewPdfComponent
    // has initialized
    this.somethingChanged.emit();
  }
  ...

  // Also whenever something changes, just call `this.somethingChanged.emit();`
}
```

Now in the template of `OrderDetailComponent`, you can bind to `somethingChanged` by doing `(somethingChanged)="exportPdf()"`. Try this:

```
<div>
  <order-review-pdf 
    [commissionIncentive]="commissionIncentive" 
    [orderEntry]="orderEntry" 
    [siteSurvey]='siteSurvey'
    (somethingChanged)="exportPdf()">
  </order-review-pdf>
</div>
```

So this way, you won't be needing the `isOpenReviewPDF` boolean property in your `OrderDetailComponent`

Comment: How I can use exportPdf() at the second time? I saw you code just use 1 time.

Comment: I meant exportPdf() again. When i change some things on parent component and need exportPdf() agian, call export pdf on children component might not good in this case

Comment: my question means how to ensure the chilren component has been initialzed yet after i opened the indicator show children component?

Comment: I use this.isOpenReviewPDF = true because the review component is quite big. So i dont want to show this component in other action. I just want to show when click exportPdf. That means click export -> set this.isOpenReviewPDF = true -> wait this.reviewPdfCoopoment.isInit === true. After that do some thing.

Comment: Btw, i click export(). Then click() export. Then click(“ export(). Is emit work with 3 times to click export?